# Can anyone help translate this Kanji?

Tags: kanji

Can someone please help me translate this kanji? I saw it on a tattoo and would like to know what it means. Thank you so very much in advance!

[image]

Comment: It's this character 然. It means nature or spontaneity.

Answer (score 1):

[According to a Kanji dictionary](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%84%B6) 然 have two meanings.

> 1. しかり、ただしい。肯定・是認の意を表す。
> 2. ある状態にある。その状態である意を表す。

First meaning is "right", or "correct". The second meaning is "something is at some status".

In practical Japanese language, you usually don't use 然 alone, but you usually use with combination of other Kanji. Here is some examples.自然(nature, naturally), 必然(necessary), 偶然(contingency), 漠然(abstract, ambiguous).

As you might notice, 然 only have abstract meaning, and the meaning can be change a lot depending on the conbination of other Kanji.

Comment: I think you meant to say 'coincidence' for 偶然。 _(contingence_ works as a translation but is a rare word in modern English.)

Comment: @oals Right. I meant 'coincidence'. Thanks for pointing out.